# Data output costs in Kinesis Data Stream when connecting many eventbridge pipes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-event-bridge

If we connect two EventBridge Pipes to a kinesis Data Stream (Customer Orders) then the cost of data output from the kinesis doubles? and so on if we add more Eventbridge Pipes to Kinesis?

Link to serverlessland sample: https://serverlessland.com/patterns/eventbridge-pipes-kinesis-to-kinesis-with-filtering

[image: eventbridge-pipes-kinesis-to-kinesis-with-filtering]

Comment: This depends on whether you have provisioned or on-demand streams. On-demand does charge per GB of data retrieved, so yes, adding multiple consumers will increase the costs. Provisioned streams do not charge for retrieval, and their primary cost is per shard-hour. The real question, however, should be "am I sending enough data through this stream that the egress costs matter?"